# Does anyone know how to test a callback function using Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to test my, then, call back function but have no idea on how to do it. Can anyone help

Here is my code:

```
return props.addMember(params, phoneNumber).then(() => {
            props.reset();
            this.props.getGroupDetails({
                MSISDN: groupAdminNumber,
                GROUP_ID: groupID,
            })
        });
```

Comment: Give a [mcve] of code and test - what's triggering this code, and what's the problem with your test so far? You can generally just pass spies as the callable props and make sure they're called as required.

Comment: Haven't been able to write a test since I can't figure where to start from

Comment: That's not specific enough for an SO question, I can only recommend reading up on the test libraries (runner, renderer, ...) you're using and giving a [mcve] if you come across a particular problem.